# UpdatePanel's PostbackTrigger that is inside a usercontrol inside a masterpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, master-pages

I have a masterpage and inside that masterage is a user control that has a toolbar with a save button. I then have an aspx page that inherits form t he master page. In that page I have and updatepanel. Is it possible to set the post back trigger to the Save button inside the usercontrol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a different approach of find my controls. I used [this](http://tekstem.com/QuestionDetail/134/Using-Find-Control-in-ASPNET) method. I have used this in the past and not sure why I didn't think about it earlier. In my user control I expose controls as properties. In my master page I created a property that allows me to get the user control instance. In my page I can call this:  Master.UserControlName.PropertyInControl

So, if I expose a button or control in the user control, I should be able to add that to the trigger collection.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `Master.FindControl("MySaveButton")` from within the content page, and attach it to the scriptmanager's trigger list:

```
this.MyScriptManager.RegisterAsynchPostBackControl(Master.FindControl("MySaveButton"))
```

Unless I'm not understanding the question correctly.

Comment: I would need to find the control thorugh the master and into the user control, correct?  I guess it would look like this: Master.FindControl("UserControl").FindControl("TheButton")

Answer (score 0):

Check the fourth post down (marked as answer) [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1124967.aspx), it ought to help.

In short, create an `PostBackTrigger` instance, set fields appropriately and then add to the `UpdatePanel`'s `Triggers` collection.

For example (from linked site):

```
//Creates a new async trigger
AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();

//Sets the control that will trigger a post-back on the UpdatePanel
trigger.ControlID = "btnCommit";

//Sets the event name of the control
trigger.EventName = "Click";

//Adds the trigger to the UpdatePanels' triggers collection
pnlMain.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

Comment: I like this, but where does this code go? Like I said I have a master page and in that master page is a tool bar user control. The button is inside that user control. When I base a page off my master and put an update panel onthat page do I set the ControlID to the ID of the button in the user control?